# Runaway simulation in gazebo 9?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello list,

I have a simple model, consisting of 4 boxes/cylinders and 3 revolute joints, very basic.
It is controlled using the joint trajectory controller with a simple python script.
It is not connected to ground, it effectively is a box that can push itself on the ground with the rest of the model.

Here a [short video](http://fwn06.housing.rug.nl/Rowing/boot0.mp4), exported from gazebo that show's it in action.

And [here](http://fwn06.housing.rug.nl/Rowing/boot0_project.tar.gz) the complete project.

But after 3 second the model starts to "oscillate" violently. The joints suddenly don't seem to be revolute anymore.
This smells like a bug.

Using gazebo-9 ros-melodic from source on debian testing.

**Edit:** Somtimes gzclient crashes with:

```
gzclient: /build/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/include/OgreAxisAlignedBox.h:252: void Ogre::AxisAlignedBox::setExtents(const Ogre::Vector3&, const Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion `(min.x <= max.x && min.y <= max.y && min.z <= max.z) && "The minimum corner of the box must be less than or equal to maximum corner"' failed.
Aborted
```

Is there anything I can do? Thanks in advance, Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20800/runaway-simulation-in-gazebo-9?/) by [Sietse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6373/sietse/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

To answer my own question, from an answer from [my question](https://answers.ros.org/question/306854/joint-trajectory-controller-erratic-behaviour-in-gazebo/) on ros-answers:
the origin elements of the inertial element in the links were not set properly in the urdf

When setting them the same as the collision and visual elements everything works properly.

---

Originally posted by [Sietse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6373/sietse/) with karma: 25 on 2018-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1